# Can I include nested ES2015 maps and sets in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, ecmascript-6, set

I want to convert some complex JavaScript objects to JSON (e.g. before saving the data to a file). These objects may contain arbitrarily nested data values of any type, including ES6/ES2015 maps and/or sets. e.g.

```
const myOriginalObject = {
    a: [1, new Set([2, new Map()]), 3],
    c: {d: new Map([['e', 4], ['f', new Set()]])}
};
```

However, `JSON.stringify` causes the map/set data to be lost. So, is there a way I can maintain the data in maps and sets when stored as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `replacer` function with `JSON.stringify` and a corresponding `reviver` function with `JSON.parse` that converts the maps and/or sets to standard JavaScript arrays and back again. e.g.

**replacer and reviver functions:**

```
const replacer = (k, v) =>
    v instanceof Map ? ({_WAS_MAP: [...v]}) :
    v instanceof Set ? ({_WAS_SET: [...v]}) : v;

const reviver = (k, v) =>
    v && v._WAS_MAP ? new Map(v._WAS_MAP) :
    v && v._WAS_SET ? new Set(v._WAS_SET) : v;
```

This technique uses, for example, [a map-to-array conversion strategy](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html) within `JSON.stringify` and simultaneously "marks" the new array as having been derived from a map, e.g. it converts `Map { 'a' => 1 }` to `{"_WAS_MAP":[["a",1]]}`. Then, later, `JSON.parse` can look for properties labeled `_WAS_MAP` and know to convert those back to maps. A similar strategy can work for sets.

**example code:**

```
const myOriginalObject = {
    a: [1, new Set([2, new Map()]), 3],
    c: {d: new Map([['e', 4], ['f', new Set()]])}
};

console.log('original:', myOriginalObject);
const mySavedJson = JSON.stringify(myOriginalObject, replacer);
console.log('JSON:', mySavedJson);
const myRetrievedObject = JSON.parse(mySavedJson, reviver);
console.log('retrieved:', myRetrievedObject); // all data is recovered
```

**output** (whitespace edited for clarity):

```
original:  { a :[1,       Set  {2,       Map  {}  },3], c :{ d:        Map  { 'e' => 4,  'f' =>     Set  {}   }}}
JSON:      {"a":[1,{"_WAS_SET":[2,{"_WAS_MAP":[]}]},3],"c":{"d":{"_WAS_MAP":[["e",   4],["f",{"_WAS_SET":[]}]]}}}
retrieved: { a :[1,       Set  {2,       Map  {}  },3], c :{ d:        Map  { 'e' => 4,  'f' =>     Set  {}   }}}
```

*(I have not included the above code in a working code snippet because, while `console.log` shows the map and set data as above when run in, e.g., node, it does not show when run in a code snippet on StackOverflow.)*